# When we use the new struct initialization format, do unlisted members have an unspecified value?

Tags: c

So I have a large struct that I need to prepare:

```
struct Config {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    struct { int x; int y; } d[40];
};
```

I'd like to fill this as such:

```
Config config = {
    .a = 3;
    .b = 4;
    .d[0] = {10, 12};
    .d[1] = {14, 16};
};
```

After this, does the value of `config.c` and `config.d[2]` have an unspecified value? or is it zero?

Or, am I required to do:

```
Config config;
memset(&config, 0, sizeof(config));
config.a = 3;
config.b = 4;
config.d[0].x = 10;
config.d[0].y = 12;
...
```

Comment: Your `memset` call is not guaranteed to set non-integer fields to `0`. null pointers and `0.0` floating-point numbers are not necessarily represented as all-bits-zero (though they very commonly are). The implicit zero initialization mentioned in [jwodder's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24706192/827263) is guaranteed to use the appropriate representation for `0`, `0.0`, or `NULL`.

Comment: The technical term for this kind of initialization is "designated initializer".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are initialized to zero.

From the C99 standard, §6.7.8, item 19:

> The initialization shall occur in initializer list order, each initializer provided for a particular subobject overriding anypreviously listed initializer for the same subobject; all subobjects that are not initialized explicitly shall be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration.

The rules for initialization of `static` objects are specified earlier in item 10:

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is indeterminate. If an object that has static storage duration is not initialized explicitly, then:
>
> - if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
> - if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;
> - if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules;
> - if it is a union, the ﬁrst named member is initialized (recursively) according to these 
>     rules.